# Excel 2013, Cells Will Not Protect

Tags: excel, locking, worksheet

Excel 2013:
Trying to lock all but a few cells on a worksheet. Some text cells will not lock. 
Is there a bug? or is there a more advanced formatting or setting i need to use?
thank you!

Note that I:
1)  locked the entire worksheet (format cells/protection/click "lock") 
2)  then went to Review/Protect Worksheet, and entered a password
3)  tested. Numerical cells were protected, as designed; SOME text cells were not locked. SOME were protected properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try right click > Format Cells > Protection > Locked

Hidden and Locked both have functionality here. Recall that you must Protect Sheets in addition to protecting a workbook.

Comment: Thanks. I had not protected both sheets and workbook; thought only one was needed. Will give that a try.

Comment: Locking both the worksheets - and the workbook helped. None of the numerical fields can be altered without unlocking now.  BUT there is a bug; a few text fields can still be altered - even after locking those fields, protecting the worksheet and protecting the workbook.                    Thanks for the help!